# Created hook gets data then updates Vuex state but nothing in DOM

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to have my object of arrays that come from firebase be rendered as cards on my main page (like an Instagram feed). on my App.vue I have a create() lifecycle hook to go get my data and then dispatch an action that will use a mutation to set state.

In another created() hook within my Card component I grab the state and use it in a v-for.

What is happening is in Vue tools I can see the state has been added properly, and when I use a v-for within my component it should appear on my main page. The odd thing is if I wait a while without updating page my items will appear. If I refresh my page they vanish again.

I've tried using a settimeout() in my card component to see if waiting in the created() hook would work but it did not. Here is where I use the created() in my app.vue

```
    export default {
  name: 'app',
  data() {
    return {
      cards: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    Card
  },
  created() {
    db.collection('Assets').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
        this.cards.push(doc.data());

        this.$store.dispatch('actionCards', this.cards)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

here is my store.js

```
const Store = new Vuex.Store({
     state: {
        loadedCards:[],
        user: null,
        username: null,
        token: null
     },
     mutations: {
    setCards(state, cards) {
      state.loadedCards = cards;
    }
       actions: {
       actionCards(vuexContext, cards) {
        vuexContext.commit('setCards', cards)
     }
```

My card component code where I get the state.

```
 export default {
name: 'card',
data() {
    return {
        cards: []
    }
}, 
created() {
    this.$store.state.loadedCards.forEach( (doc) => {

           this.cards.push(doc) 


     })
 }
```

}

I am hoping for my card to render right away.

Comment: Rather than taking the `loadedCards` from the store and putting them in a local data property, consider making a computed method such as `computed:{ cards () { return this.$store.state.loadedCards; } }`

Comment: Computed methods cache the result, until one of their dependencies change.  In this case, if the store loadedCards changed, the computed method would immediately re-evaluate, and any logic you have in your template depending upon them, such as a v-for, would auto update.

Comment: @taplar Thanks a bunch it worked perfectly